# How to use Embedded MongoDB on Spring Boot Integration tests

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to use EmbeddedMongoDB to work on my tests.

Here are my codes:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MyWebServiceApplication.class, TestMongoConfig.class})
public class MyWebServiceApplicationTests {

@Autowired 
InfoRepository repository;

@Before
public void setUp() {

}

@Test
public void setsIdOnSave() {
    Info dave = repository.findInfoByMobileNumber(917900);
    assertThat(dave.getCarrier(), is(notNullValue()));
    }
}
```

If I remove TestMongoConfig.class, the test works but it is connecting to the live DB.

Here's the TestMongoConfig class. [I got this code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568351/how-do-you-configure-embedded-mongdb-for-integration-testing-in-a-spring-boot-ap/35204466)

```
@Configuration
public class TestMongoConfig {

@Autowired
private MongoProperties properties;

@Autowired(required = false)
private MongoClientOptions options;

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public Mongo mongo(MongodProcess mongodProcess) throws IOException {
    Net net = mongodProcess.getConfig().net();
    properties.setHost(net.getServerAddress().getHostName());
    properties.setPort(net.getPort());
    return properties.createMongoClient(this.options);
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
public MongodProcess mongodProcess(MongodExecutable mongodExecutable) throws IOException {
    return mongodExecutable.start();
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
public MongodExecutable mongodExecutable(MongodStarter mongodStarter, IMongodConfig iMongodConfig) throws IOException {
    return mongodStarter.prepare(iMongodConfig);
}

@Bean
public IMongodConfig mongodConfig() throws IOException {
    return new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION).build();
}

@Bean
public MongodStarter mongodStarter() {
    return MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
}

}
```

Now, I am getting this error:

```
Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoProperties com.example.TestMongoConfig.properties
```

Please note that my application is connecting to two different MongoDB instances. My configuration for the "live" connection isn't using Autoconfiguration and it has its own beans. [Here's my reference for achieving this.](https://falkenfighter.wordpress.com/2015/10/13/multiple-databases-with-spring-boot-mongodb-repositories/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = { "package1", "package2" })
public class TestMongoConfig {

@Autowired
private MongoProperties properties;

@Autowired(required = false)
private MongoClientOptions options;

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public Mongo mongo(MongodProcess mongodProcess) throws IOException {
    Net net = mongodProcess.getConfig().net();
    properties.setHost(net.getServerAddress().getHostName());
    properties.setPort(net.getPort());
    return properties.createMongoClient(this.options);
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
public MongodProcess mongodProcess(MongodExecutable mongodExecutable) throws IOException {
    return mongodExecutable.start();
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
public MongodExecutable mongodExecutable(MongodStarter mongodStarter, IMongodConfig iMongodConfig) throws IOException {
    return mongodStarter.prepare(iMongodConfig);
}

@Bean
public IMongodConfig mongodConfig() throws IOException {
     return new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
            .cmdOptions(new MongoCmdOptionsBuilder().useNoJournal(true)
                    .useStorageEngine("mmapv1")
         .build())
            .build(); 
}

@Bean
public MongodStarter mongodStarter() {
    return MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
}

}
```

**@EnableAutoConfiguration** 
and 
**@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = { "package1", "package2" })** 
needs to be there. I am guessing that it's how Spring Boot integrates embedded MongoDB into it's CrudRepository

Next is this code:

```
     return new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
            .cmdOptions(new MongoCmdOptionsBuilder().useNoJournal(true)
                    .useStorageEngine("mmapv1")
         .build())
            .build();
```

That is my code as I am running this in a 32 bit machine. I had to set mmapv1 and set useNoJournal to fix the **Could not start process: EOF error** I am having.

For the error

```
Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoProperties com.example.TestMongoConfig.properties
```

I have to create an application.properties containing the same stuff I have in the main codes.

Comment: @vinothkumar yes, it solved my issue. But I have upgrade my os and mongodb to 64 bit.

Comment: For me it is taking the actual configuration from app-context.xml

Comment: Ah... For my case, I use Spring Boot and had to avoid xml configuration files. So most of the stuff I have to use is annotations

Comment: It's on the answer I posted. What part do you need help?