# The easiest way to configure Embedded MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm wondering, is there any example how to properly configure embedded `MongoDB` with `Spring Boot`?

For example, this is how i configure H2 embedded database:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean;

import javax.sql.DataSource;


@Configuration
@PropertySource({"configs/datasource.properties"})
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @Profile("test")
    public DataSource testDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }
}
```

And this works well, but there is a problem. This approach doesnt provide configuration with MongoDB.

Are there any workarounds?

**UPDATE 1:**

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run
>   (default-cli) on project XXX: An exception occurred while
>   running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with
>   name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource
>   [com/reborn/XXX/config/DataSourceConfig .class]: Bean
>   instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.springframewor k.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]:
>   Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/flapdoodle/embed/mongo/distribu
>   tion/IFeatureAwareVersion:
>   de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.distribution.IFeatureAwareVersion -> [Help
>   1]

**UPDATE 2:**

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.reborn</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>xxx</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repositories -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**DatasourceConfig:**

```
package com.reborn.xxx.config;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import cz.jirutka.spring.embedmongo.EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws IOException {
        EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean mongo = new EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean();
        mongo.setBindIp("localhost");
        MongoClient mongoClient = mongo.getObject();
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, "abcd");
        return mongoTemplate;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 3:**

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project starbucks-finder: An exception occurred while
>   running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/reborn/xxx/config/DataSourceConfig
>   .class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframewor
>   k.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: this version does not support
>   32Bit: PRODUCTION:Windows:B32 -> [Help 1]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you configure Embedded MongDB for integration testing in a Spring Boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568351/how-do-you-configure-embedded-mongdb-for-integration-testing-in-a-spring-boot-ap)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [flapdoodle embedded MongoDB](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) can be integrated with Spring Boot.

- Declare a dependency on flapdoodle:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Declare a dependency on the library, to provide a Spring factory bean for flapdoodle's embedded MongoDB:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
      <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Presumably, you have already declared a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`:

  ```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Now, just configure a `MongoTemplate` pointing at the embedded MongoDB instance:

  ```
  @Bean
  public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws IOException {
      EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean mongo = new EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean();
      mongo.setBindIp("localhost");
      MongoClient mongoClient = mongo.getObject();
      MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, "test_or_whatever_you_want_to_call_this_db");
      return mongoTemplate;
  }
  ```

Comment: There is some issues with project launching. See topic update.

Comment: @Reborn are you saying that you updated the original question to describe "some issues with project launching"? If so, I cannot see any **details** describing this issue. Perhaps you could [provide a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: This exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/flapdoodle/embed/mongo/distribution/IFeatureAwareVersion` implies that either (1) you haven't added the `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` dependency or (2) you haven't run `mvn install` after adding the `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` dependency and before running `mvn spring-boot:run`. Could you please update your question to include (1) your updated pom.xml and (2) your declaration of `MongoTemplate`.

Comment: Topic updated. `start.spring.io` already added most of dependencies that you told except `cz.jirutka.spring`. I've done `mvn clean install` multiple times to make sure everything is working as it should be, but as you can see there is still an issue.

Comment: You haven't specified a version for the `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` dependency which means, for Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE, you are using v1.50.5. I verified the implementation in my post using v2.0.0 (i.e. the version explicitly referenced in my answer). However, v1.50.5 of `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` also includes `IFeatureAwareVersion` so that should be ok. AFAICT, your setup is valid, can your browse to `IFeatureAwareVersion` in your IDE? Have you checked that this file: `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-1.50.5.jar` exists in your local Maven repo and that it contains `IFeatureAwareVersion`?

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, when you dont specify dependency in pom, then maven picks the latest from repository? Anyway, i just append `<version>2.0.0</version>` and removed `test` scope, but now it says i have another issue. See Update 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153269/discussion-between-reborn-and-glitch).

Answer (score 3):

For Spring Boot 2.2.x with JUnit5

**pom.xml**

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**Test class**
*(With ability to set MongoDB  version)*

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataMongoTest
class ModelRepoIntegrationTest {

    private static final String IP = "localhost";
    private static final int PORT = 28017; // <- set MongoDB port

    @TestConfiguration
    @Import(ModelRepo.class) // <- set the tested repository
    // @ComponentScan("com.example.repo") <- or package for several repositories
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        public IMongodConfig embeddedMongoConfiguration() throws IOException {
            return new MongodConfigBuilder()
                    .version(Version.V4_0_2) // <- set MongoDB version
                    .net(new Net(IP, PORT, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Autowired private ModelRepo repo; // <- tested repository
    @Autowired private MongoTemplate mongo; 

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() { // clean db (slower) or collection (faster) before each test
        // mongo.getDb().drop();
        mongo.remove(new Query(), Model.class); 
    }

    @Test
    void create() {
        Model model = new Model() // <- tested entity
                          .setId(UUID.randomUUID())
                          .setNum(1)
                          .setText("text");
        Model actual = repo.create(model); // <- tested method of the repository
        List<Model> models = mongo.findAll(Model.class);
        assertThat(models).hasSize(1);
        Model expected = models.get(0);
        assertThat(actual).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(expected);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it will auto configure with new or compitable version of relevant dependencies

```
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


<dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <version>1.50.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


        @Repository
public interface yourRepository extends MongoRepository<Class Type, String> {

}
```