# How to use Embedded MongoDB in Spring Boot 2.2 integration tests?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, integration-testing

I want to use Embedded MongoDB instance instead of connecting to my localhost MongoDB.

In integration tests I use only mockMvc.
Annotations on my test class

```
@Profile("it")
@SpringBootTest
//@DataMongoTest - tried to do with that and can't run app because of missing Security beans.
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class ControllerIntegrationTest {
   @Autowired
   private WebApplicationContext context;

   @Autowired
   private MockMvc mockMvc;
...
}
```

MongoDB config

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class MongodbConfiguration {

   @Value("${mongo.db.url:mongodb://127.0.0.1}")
   private String MONGO_DB_URL;

   @Value(("${mongo.db.port:27017}"))
   private int MONGO_DB_PORT;

   @Value("${mongo.db.name:admin}")
   private String MONGO_DB_NAME;

   @Bean
   public MongoClient mongo() {
      return MongoClients.create(MONGO_DB_URL + ":" + MONGO_DB_PORT);
   }

   @Bean
   public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory(MongoClient mongoClient) {
      return new SimpleMongoClientDbFactory(mongoClient, MONGO_DB_NAME);
   }

   @Bean
   public WriteConcernResolver writeConcernResolver() {
      return action -> {
         System.out.println("Using Write Concern of MAJORITY");
         return WriteConcern.MAJORITY;
      };
   }

   @Bean
   public MongoCustomConversions customConversions(OffsetDateTimeReadConverter offsetDateTimeReadConverter,
         OffsetDateTimeWriteConverter offsetDateTimeWriteConverter) {
      return new MongoCustomConversions(asList(offsetDateTimeReadConverter, offsetDateTimeWriteConverter));
   }
}
```

I have "de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:2.2.0" in my build.gradle file:

```
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4"
    testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.16.1"
    integrationTest "de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:2.2.0"
```

I was trying to do that as stated in [How to make the junit tests use the embedded mongoDB in a springboot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039644/how-to-make-the-junit-tests-use-the-embedded-mongodb-in-a-springboot-application), however it's from 2018 so it may be outdated.

Whenever I run test it still tries to connect to localhost MongoDB instance instead run embedded.

Answer (score -3):

Given it's an IT I'd suggest you to use MongoDB container to run your test, it will give you more precise insights about your app and can be integrated with a CI/CD pipeline.